# Does L have a definition in terms of circuits?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, circuit-complexity

Many complexity classes defined with Turing machines have definitions in terms of uniform circuits. For example, P can also be defined using uniform polynomial size circuits, and similarly BPP, NP, BQP, etc. can be defined with uniform circuits.

> So is there a circuit-based definition of L?

An obvious idea would be to allow polynomial size circuits with some depth limitation, but this turn out to define the NC hierarchy.

I was thinking about this question a long time ago, but didn't find an answer. If I remember correctly, my motivation was to understand what the quantum analog of L would look like.

Comment: Do logarithmic sized circuits contain $L$?

Comment: @Turkistany: No, I don't think so, since a log size circuit can at most have log depth, and thus is contained in NC_1, which is defined as log depth, poly size circuits. NC_1 is contained in L, and not known to be equal to L.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, $L = SC^1$, where $SC^1$ is the class of languages computed by polynomial size circuits of $O(\log n)$ width.

As for $NL$, it could be characterized as the class languages computed by polynomial size *skew* circuits (which in some sense is just another way of saying nondeterministic branching programs).

Comment: We need the circuits to be uniform, right?

Comment: Correct, they should be uniform.

Comment: [$SC^1$](http://qwiki.stanford.edu/index.php/Complexity_Zoo:S#sc) is defined using Turing Machines as $DTimeSpace(poly,log)$ so it is already uniform.

Comment: @KristofferArnsfeltHansen: It's been a while since you've answered this, but do you have a reference where the equivalence between the circuit and TM definitions of L is proved?

Comment: @Robin, I can't think of it, actually. Perhaps Vinay knows?

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I'll just clarify the definition once again. I guess you mean polynomial size, log width circuits over unbounded fanin AND, OR, NOT gates, where the input of the circuit is $x$? And we enforce (say) log space uniformity, so that on input $1^n$ there is a log space TM that outputs the circuit $C_n$ which computes the function for all $n$-bit inputs $x$?

Answer (score 13):

Check out this paper of 
[McKenzie, Reinhardt, Vinay](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~mckenzie/mcrevi99.ps). We use multiplex-select gates to characterize classes between $NC^1$ and $LOGCFL$, including $L$, $LOGDCFL$ etc. For example, $L = MWidth, Size(log,poly).$

$NL$ has a natural circuit based characterization using Skew Circuits. This is just a circuit representation of the branching program that represents $NL$. Skew circuits are due to Venkateswaran.